# How to stop Android Studio 3.6 of generate new fragments

Tags: android-studio

I just downloaded the new Android Studio 3.6.1 and there's something annoying about it. Every time that I tried to create a new activity it generates two new fragments with a navigation file. How can I disable this?

[image]

Comment: Which new activity template are you selecting? "Empty Activity" shouldn't generate any fragments with it.

Comment: What are you doing to create the activity?

Comment: It's the Basic Activity before the Update it wasn't like that!

Comment: @NathielPaulino why not use EmptyActivity instead?

Comment: Also Basic Activity does not create  fragments for me...